# How do I write to a file in Matlab?

Tags: matlab, file-io

I have an mXn matrix of integers. I want to write the matrix to a text file. I also want to read the file later and assign the values to another mXn matrix. How?

EDIT: I want it to be as easy as possible to later load the content of the file to a variable in matlab (a matrix). I also might use the file in a C program where I load the numbers in the file to an mXn array.

Comment: what format would you like the file? Matlab has its own file format (.mat file) which allows you to save the state of the workspace.
You can also do things like save to excel and comma seperate files... amongst other supported formats

Comment: @Fuzz, I want to write to a text file (just edited my question to mention this).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See the functions [save](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/save.html) and [load](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/load.html).

Answer (score 0):

Would [DLMREAD](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/dlmread.html)/[DLMWRITE](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/dlmwrite.html) work for you?